Using \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} with a \begin{itemize} and text before that block breaks text selection
I need to use \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} to ensure effective text selection for German PDF documents. However, if I add a list anywhere within my document with \begin{itemize} breaks the text selection. Presumably it's some issue with the combination of using MacTeX or pdfLaTeX or Preview, but any pointer is helpful at this point. As my students often use the highlighter features of their tablet computers, it would be good if there was a way to have the working text highlighting back.
I am aware that this might be a beginner's issue, but searching around yielded no helpful results. It also made no difference using lmodern instead as a font.
The following snippet is a simple document to reproduce this issue:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{libertine}

\begin{document}
    Text before Itemize
    
    \begin{itemize}
        \item hello 123
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}

The text selection looks like this within Preview:

Whereas without any itemize it yields a correct selection:


Welcome to TeX.SX!

Note that text selection and the highligher might be different things. I have no issue highligthing or text selecting this in Evince on linux using pdflatex and TeXLive 2024. As differenct viewers may behave differently it will be useful to know exaxctly which software the students with issues are using.

It also works fine in Okular on Linux (in X11 - haven't tried Wayland). pdfTeX and TL 2024. Is MacTeX up to date? If so, does it work in a different PDF viewer?

Just for a try, select the text without the Bullet

Thanks for the welcoming feedback! I have tried out my file with Evince and it in fact displays the highlights correctly. Compiling it with TL 2024 and opening it on my Mac and the issue persists, so I assume it is an issue with Preview/macOS. Most of my students (~60%) use an iPad and the issue also persists there, so I'll report this issue to Apple. Selecting without the bullet also shows the same behavior.
